# How to use Drupal xhprof to profile node save?

Tags: drupal-7, xhprof

Using Drupal [xhprof](https://www.drupal.org/project/xhprof), when saving a node after edit, the page goes to the node view page. So the profiling result of the page is the view page.

I want to profile the "save" operation which seems slow. How can I achieve that?